# How to ensure idempotency on event hub on consumers that only stores aggregated information?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, microservices, azure-eventhub, event-driven

I'm working on an event-driven micro-services architecture and I'm using eventhubs to send a lot of data (around 20-30k events per minute) to multiple consumer groups and I'm using Azure Functions EventHubTrigger to process these events.

The data I'm passing around has a unique identifier and my other consumers can guarantee idempotency since I'm storing them on their data stores as well upon processing - so if the unique event identifier already exists, I can skip processing for that specific event.

I do however have one service that only does data-aggregation for reporting to a relational database - doing counts, sums, and what-not. Pretty much upserts so that I can do some queries against it to produce reports - and I did see quite a bit of events that have been processed multiple times.

So an idea that I had was to just have some sort of event store. Redis with TTL, or Azure Table Storage, or even a table on my relational database that only contains a single field with a unique constraint so I can do a transaction on the whole event processing.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Database transaction sounds good. If you encounter some performance issues because of transaction locks you may also think about using redis as the store for unique event ids. You can check that before and after processing to fasten your overall process. Still database sounds like a solid solution.

Comment: Azure Table sounds great for your purpose. The Partition/Row keys indexing on the table has great performance if you want to fetch a specific row and it's crazy cheap!

Comment: You could also consider the capture functionality of event hubs. [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/store-captured-data-data-warehouse)

Comment: hey guys! thanks for the responses - I was hoping more though but I'm leaning towards using transactions for atomicity and that I didn't have to use a separate retry mechanism just for a separate event store. performance-wise, I feel like I'm on the clear for now with batching and relatively few partitions.

I am interested though, on how I can achieve idempotency using the capture functionality as mentioned by @PrebenHuybrechts, I've seen that documentation before, but I'm not sure how I can use that to prevent my unique events from being processed multiple times. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Typically you would store your events in a blob or table storage and if you have the same event you override it. After some time you process your storage account to a data lake where you can then aggregate the data.

Comment: ah! data lake! I feel like we should be using that instead of manually shaping our data into an azure SQL database - unfortunately though, we don't have much experience with that yet - I guess this calls for more reading and research. Thanks you for that!

edit: I've seen the pricing on data like analytics :) I guess we'll stay on Azure SQL for now. haha